# Display flash messages after submiting a php form

Tags: php, forms, redirect, notifications, flash-message

I want to display some notifications after submiting a form in php.
I don't know if I'm doing the right way... 
I want to submit my form, refresh my datas inside the form and display the notification.

For example, this is my add function :

```php
public function addNewPost(){
    $manager = new PostsManager($this->db);
    if(isset($_POST['publish'])){
        if (empty($_POST['title']) || empty($_POST['header']) || empty($_POST['author']) || empty($_POST['content']))
        {
            $_SESSION['addPostDatas'] = $_POST;
            $session = new Session();
            $session->setFlash('"Title", "Header", "Author" and "Content are required and cannot be empty"');
            $session->flash();
            header('Location: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        }
        else
        { 
            $newpost = new Post([
                        'title' => $_POST['title'],
                        'header' => $_POST['header'],
                        'author' => $_POST['author'],
                        'date' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
                        'content' => $_POST['content'],
                        'featuredImg' => $this->uploadImg()
                        ]); 
            $manager->add($newpost); // Create a new post
            unset($_SESSION['addPostDatas']);
            header('Location: index.php?p=blog');
            $session = new Session();
            $session->setFlash('The post was published !', 'success');
            $session->flash();
        }
    }
}
```

In my case, nothing is displayed, I don't know how to do.

My session class is like this :

```php
Class Session{

    public function __construct(){
        if(!isset($_SESSION)){ 
            session_start(); 
        } 
    }

    public function setFlash($message, $type = 'danger'){
        $_SESSION['flash'] = array(
            'message' => $message,
            'type'    => $type
        );
    }

    public function flash(){
        if(isset($_SESSION['flash'])){
            ?>
            <div id="alert" class="alert alert-<?php echo $_SESSION['flash']['type'] ?>" role="alert">
                 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>

                <strong><?php print_r($_SESSION['flash']['message']); ?></strong>
            </div>
            <?php
            unset($_SESSION['flash']);
        }
    }

}
```

Can you explain to me the way to do this ?

Thanks a lot !

**EDIT**

This is my index.php

```php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use natinho68\Models\SPDO as SPDO;

use natinho68\Controllers\Session as Session;
use natinho68\Models\PostsManager as PostsManager;
use natinho68\Controllers\MailController as MailController;
use natinho68\Controllers\Controller as Controller;


$db = new SPDO();
$session = new Session();
$posts = new PostsManager($db);
$contact = new MailController();

// Routing
$page = "home";
if(isset($_GET['p'])){
    $page = $_GET['p'];
}

// Rendu du template

// Chargement des templates dans le dossier templates
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(__DIR__ . '/Views');
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, [
    'cache' => false, // __DIR__ . '/tmp'
        'debug' => true
    ]);
$twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extension_Debug());

if(!empty($_SESSION['addPostDatas'])){
$twig->addGlobal('addPostDatas', $_SESSION['addPostDatas']);    
}



$controller = new Controller($twig, $db);

switch ($page){

    case 'home' :
    $controller->home('home.twig');
        $contact->mailer();
    break;

    case 'contact' :
    echo $twig->render('contact.twig');
        $contact->mailer();
    break;

    case 'blog':
    echo $twig->render('allPosts.twig', ['allPosts' => $posts->getAllPosts()]);
    break;

    case 'singlepost' :
        $controller->showPost($_GET['id'], 'singlePost.twig');
        break;

        case 'editpost' :
        $controller->showPost($_GET['id'],'editpost.twig');
        $controller->updatePost();
        $controller->deletePost();
    break;

        case 'add-post' :
        $controller->addPostView('addPost.twig');
        $controller->addNewPost();
    break;

    default: 
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
    echo $twig->render('404.twig');
    break;
}
```

My view is like this

```php
{% extends 'layout.twig' %}
{% import 'form.twig' as form %}
{% block head %}
    <title>Add a post</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class='page-header'>
  <div class='btn-toolbar pull-right'>
    <div class='btn-group'>
      <a href="?p=blog" type="button" class="btn btn-default">View all blog posts</a>
    </div>
  </div>
    <h1>Add post</h1>
</div>
<form action="index.php?p=add-post" method="post" id="add" name="add" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ form.input('title', 'Title', addPostDatas.title)  }}
        {{ form.textarea('header', 'Header', 03, addPostDatas.header) }}
    {{ form.textareacontent('content', 'Content', 30, addPostDatas.content) }}
        {{ form.input('author', 'Author', addPostDatas.author) }}
        {{ form.file('image', 'Optional - Select a featured image (max size 4Mo)')}}
        <div class="form-group"><br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="publish">Publish the post</button>
    </div>

</form>


{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Are you working on someone elses codebase? Or is this based on some framework?

Comment: No it's my work, i'm just using twig for templating.

Comment: Well, you kind of trying to do a singleton(for session). You might want to go with it all the way.

Comment: Its going to be hard to help as the code is not public, but large parts of it are not shown (the rest of whatever class has the method `addNewPost`, `PostsManager`, `Post`, the whole routing mechanism etc. What i can say is there is a lot of weirdness. for example you seem to have a `session` class, but sporadically access `$_SESSION` as well. You attempt to display a message and perform a redirect in the same method (only one will happen) etc.

Comment: And what is point in adding stuff to session and than running it during same pageload?

Comment: TBH unless this is a purely academic exercise, you would make you life a whole lot easier (and your application a lot less buggy) by picking up a modern well documented framework that will already have all this stuff, Laravel or Symfony would be a good start

Comment: @Steve ok I understand that I can't displayed 2 notifications inside the same method ?
The weirdness it's because I'm studying php... I'm not a good developer yet :)

Comment: Sure, no offense intended, we all start somewhere. If you send a location header to the browser, it will immedialty follow it, by performing a new GET request to the url provided. So any message you attempt to show will never be seen (thats the whole reason sessions are used, to persist data between requests). The normal practice would be to call `$session->flash()` somewhere in the target route, either controller method or directly in the template. If you want more help please ask, but i stand behind my opinion that you will learn a ton more by picking up a decent framework

Comment: @Steve Well, for this project, it's a from scratch exercise. So .. I can't use Symfony or Laravel (next project). So I have to call $session->flash into my view and then IT CAN BE displayed, that's what you think ?

Comment: Yes, probably. As i commented on the answer bellow, the routing mechanism will pay a part. How does that work

Comment: You will have to make sure you have an instance of `Session` in scope in order to call it in the view though, which is another part of the bigger picture we dont know about

Comment: @Steve edit with my index.php

Comment: I know in dont have time tonight to fully go through this, but as a basic 1st step, your routing mechanism is currently broken - for example the editpost route seems to call methods relating to viewing, updating and deleting a post, one after the other, there is no way to formulate a request to do only one of those things.

Comment: pretty much all established routing mechanisms distinguish between request methods (GET POST PUT PATCH DELETE), but you could skip that and just have seperate url parameters for each, eg `case 'get-editpost'...case 'post-editpost'...case 'post-deletepost'` and make sure your links and form actions point to the correct one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For checking that session started, can you change your code?

```
public function __construct(){
    if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
        session_start();
    }
}
```

I think $_SESSION global variable always will set by default.

**UPD.**

And as I noticed, You first flash the messages and then redirect the page

**UPD2**

After quick rewiew I think your addNewPost() method must be like this

```
public function addNewPost()
{
    $session = new Session();
    $manager = new PostsManager($this->db);
    if (isset($_POST['publish'])) {
        if (empty($_POST['title']) || empty($_POST['header']) || empty($_POST['author']) || empty($_POST['content'])) {
            $_SESSION['addPostDatas'] = $_POST;
            $session->setFlash('"Title", "Header", "Author" and "Content are required and cannot be empty"');
            header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
            exit();

        } else {
            $newpost = new Post([
                'title' => $_POST['title'],
                'header' => $_POST['header'],
                'author' => $_POST['author'],
                'date' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
                'content' => $_POST['content'],
                'featuredImg' => $this->uploadImg()
            ]);
            $manager->add($newpost); // Create a new post
            unset($_SESSION['addPostDatas']);
            $session->setFlash('The post was published !', 'success');
            header('Location: index.php?p=blog');
            exit();

        }
    } else {
        $session->flash();
    }
}
```

Notice that you must call $session = new Session(); $session->flash(); when you process your success request(index.php?p=blog)

Comment: I replaced it in my construct, it still isn't displaying my notifications

Comment: yes thank you, I've changed the order (set notif, then redirect), but its not working.

Comment: In any keys, you must call your Session class, Did you do it in your view or anyplace? something like this  if(isset($_POST['publish'])){ .....} else {$session = new Session(); $session->flash();}

Comment: no I'm not, I'm using my 2 methods setFlash() and flash() directly in my controller ...

Comment: If we presume this one controller method is called no matter the request method, then the final UPD2 is getting there, but really we need to understanding the routing and view mechanism to really help

Comment: @Steve I agree with you. If go deeper, then I think this code should change from the very beginning. $session-> flash () should not output Html at once but should return at least the value of Html. And in this case, I think will be a preferable use Session class methods as static.

Comment: Yes, im sure this is really far too indepth for a SO answer, but somehow i always end up trying to answer these type of questions!

Comment: @MamikonArakelyan it's working with `header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ` for all my notifications with your update 2. But it's not working if I put another url in my header location. Sorry guys, I'm not understanding all of what you say but I try to.

Comment: this is a very dirty solution but it must work :) in your index.php after $session = new Session(); put $session->flash();

Comment: @MamikonArakelyan yes it's working thanks a lot... I'm doing dirty things... I will see with my teacher, for tonight, my brain is off. Thanks all guys